# HTML Layout, CSS align divs

Tags: css, html

I have a 3 column layout, and am trying to make it more responsive to screen size, rather than the standard set pixels for each div.

so i have a left, center and right div, in a 90% width container. The left and right floated divs are 200px a peice, but is there a way of then making the center div expand to fill the gap between the two?

If not, is there a better way of making a 3 column layout responsive to screen size?

HTML

```
<div id="leftCol">Content for  id "leftCol" Goes Here</div>
<div id="mainCol">Content for  id "mainCol" Goes Here</div>
<div id="rightCol">Content for  id "rightCol" Goes Here</div>
```

CSS

```
#leftCol {
 float: left;
 width: 200px;
}

#mainCol {
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 width: /* WHAT DO I PUT HERE ??? */
 float: left;
}

#rightCol {
 float: right;
 width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: @asked can u put yout html and css code in and one link in jsfiddle

Comment: it's rather difficult to mix 2 measurement types (pixels and percentages), and use them well. An easier approach would be 3 columns: 20%, 60%, 20% for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several approaches to this "problem". You might want to have a look at existing solutions and use one of these, or adapt them and make something that works for you.

Existing CSS frameworks that target responsive sites are:

- [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/)
- [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)
- Many more...

Dynamic Drive also has a series of layouts that offer fluid/fixed options, you might want to check these out and see if anything helps your current case: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/category/C10/

Answer (score 0):

## css

```
#left + #right + #center {
    MARGIN-LEFT: 203px;
}
#left + #content {
    MARGIN-LEFT: 203px;
}
#right + #center {
    MARGIN-RIGHT: 203px
}

#left
{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    background:#00CC99;
    height:300px;
}
#right
{
    float: right;
    width:200px;
    background:#33FF66;
    height:400px;
}
#center
{
    height:550px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#006666;
    color:#fff;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="center">here you can place your text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use width in percentage rather than in pixel.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="leftCol">Content for id "leftCol" Goes Here</div>
  <div id="mainCol">
    <div id="content">Content for id "mainCol" Goes Here</div>
  </div>
  <div id="rightCol">Content for id "rightCol" Goes Here</div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#wrap { display: table }
#wrap > div {display: table-cell}
#leftCol { width: 200px; background-color: red; }
#mainCol { background-color: green; }
#rightCol { width: 200px; background-color: blue; }
#mainCol #content { margin-left: 20px; }
```

Check it out at http://jsfiddle.net/6DP5F/